# In android how to write a dialogue box for a word in the middle of the text?

Tags: android

My question is I have a  text lets say 15-20 lines which is taken from a TXT file . on the output screen if i click  a specific word i should get a dialog with my own data..

for instance  :

Realizing the importance of **Distribution** sector in the overall economical development of the country and improving the living standards of the citizens, Government of India and the State Governments are reforming the power sector for its economical **revival** and development. The objective of power sector reforms is for creating conditions for **sustained** development of its system through promotion of efficiency, transparency, quality of service and attracting private **financing**. The ultimate goal of the ongoing reform process is to ensure that

In the above example if i click any of that bold words i should get an alert box with my data( i ll write)to each bold word ..the total data(text) belongs to a single file and i am taking the above text from outside source ( txt file) .

pls help me  to solve my request...

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by setting a on click listener on the textView .

You will have to create separate textviews for those words for which you want a dialog to appear on click

Refer to the following links:

[How to click or tap on a TextView text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328757/how-to-click-or-tap-on-a-textview-text)

[How to add click listeners into a string in Android/Java Textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442144/how-to-add-click-listeners-into-a-string-in-android-java-textview)

[How to set Listener for TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660257/how-to-set-listener-for-textview)

Don't forget to add the following attribute in you textview

**android:clickable="true"**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spannable.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html

here is a handy tutorial to get you started
http://0xwalkingice.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-clickable-span-in-textview.html